# why it works in python and give error inside TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

this code works perfect in python shell

```
>>> ser9=serial.Serial(port='COM9', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, stopbits=1, parity='N')
```

but using tkinter it gave me this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\New_ATE_ongoing\Instruments.py", line 25, in POWERS_TEST
    Powers.testing()
  File "C:\New_ATE_ongoing\Powers.py", line 54, in testing
    ser9=serial.Serial()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Comment: There's no way to give a definitive answer with the limited information you've provided - but I would guess that you're running the Tkinter code with a different current directory, that happens to contain a `serial.py` file that isn't the actual PySerial module.  You can do `import serial; print(serial.__file__)` to see exactly what module is being found.

Comment: thisi is what I get after print(serial.__file__)           C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py

Comment: – jasonharper
 what do you recommen me to do?